# Hide all Textboxes in DataTemplate of ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 (WINRT) App**. I used a **ListView** to populate items:

**DataTemplate for this ListView is:**

```
<ListView x:Name="EquipmentListView"
DataContext="{Binding}">                    
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
                <Grid x:Name="ViewGrid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto">                                            
                    </RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*">
                    </RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid x:Name="ViewGridTitle"
                        Grid.Row="0" Tapped="ViewGridTitle_Tapped" >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding EquipmentTitle}" 
                                Grid.Column="0" >
                                </TextBlock>
                                <Image  Grid.Column="1" 
                                x:Name="ArrowHolder"                                              
                                Source="ms-appx:///Images/ic_arrow_down.png"  >
                                </Image>
                        </Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding EquipmentDetails}" 
                        Grid.Row="1"   
                        x:Name="EquipmentDetails">
                        </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

On clicking any **ViewGridTitle** , all the **EquipmentDetails textblocks** in listView should hide.
How to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show/Hide a control in DataTemplate in UserControl in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429749/show-hide-a-control-in-datatemplate-in-usercontrol-in-wpf)

Comment: You could bind the `TextBlock` visibility to a property as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7429749/3581917).

Comment: @Mike. No. That is a bit different question

Comment: Ok.  Could you use the same technique, by binding the `ViewGridTitle_Tapped` property, via a [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=VS.100).aspx), to the `TextBlock.Visibility' by using the relative source binding?

Comment: Thankyou, Thats what I am trying to do, I tried looking at http://www.rhyous.com/2011/02/22/binding-visibility-to-a-bool-value-in-wpf/ but not helping